# how to get array from ArrayList<>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
ArrayList<int[]> queue = new ArrayList<>();
       if (isValid(x, y, colorFill, colorBoundary, graphics)){
           int[] add = new int[2];
           add[0]=x;
           add[1]=y;
           queue.add(add);

       }
       while (!queue.isEmpty()){
          int[] get = queue.get(queue.size());
          graphics.putPixel(get[0],get[1],colorFill);
          queue.remove(queue.size());...}
```

hey I have problem with geting array from  ArrayList queue = new ArrayList<>();. Do you have any
suggestions where I have made mistake?

Comment: Your should probably change `queue.size()` to `queue.size()-1` if you want to access/remove the last element.

Comment: As I remember `ArrayList` cannot be of priitive type, try use `Integer[]` (instead of int[])

Comment: @AsfK an `int[]` is not a primitive, it inherits from `Object`, so it's a legitimate base type for a generic collection.

Comment: When you say "I have a problem", please also add what the problem is. Do you get an error message? If so, include it in your question. Do you get behavior that you didn't expect? Then please [edit] the question and add the behavior you expected and what happened instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [List::get(int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-)

> Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
>   **Throws:**
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

In your question when you are writing below line:

```
queue.get(queue.size());
```

then it violate the `index >= size()` condition because you are passing **queue.size()**

Pass the index value b/w `0` and `queue.size() - 1` to get the element.

Example:

```
int[] get = queue.get(queue.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear, but I think the problem is in the following line.

```
int[] get = queue.get(queue.size());
```

This won't work since, in Java, indexes are always started with "0". So the index of the last element will be `queue.size()-1`. So the above code will return `index out of bound exception`.

Correct your code as follows;

```
int[] get = queue.get(queue.size()-1);
```